# Impossible to use vue-recaptcha-v3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am a beginner in vue.js 3. I am trying to use [vue-recaptcha-v3](https://github.com/AurityLab/vue-recaptcha-v3) which seems popular. But I do not understand how to use it.

In my `main.js`, I have :

```js
import { VueReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3'

const app = createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .use(VueReCaptcha, { siteKey: '6Lc_______________ipg' })
```

In my form I just added this :

```html
<VueReCaptcha />
```

I have this error:

[image]

(in English : "This key is not activated for the invisible captcha").

I imagine that my approach is very simple. How can I achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That seems to indicate a misconfigured site key. Also, there's no `VueReCaptcha` component (`vue-recaptcha-v3` is only a plugin that provides API methods), so don't add `<VueReCaptcha />` to your template.

Based on the [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro), these are the steps I took that worked for me:

1. [Sign up for an API key pair](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create) for your site.
2. For **Label**, enter a label for the key (e.g., `Codesandbox Demo`)
3. For **reCAPTCHA Type**, choose **reCAPTCHA v3**.
4. For **Domains**, enter the domain where the key will be used (e.g., `csb.app` for Codesandbox), and click the `+` icon.
5. Check the box for **Accept the reCAPTCHA Terms of Service**.
6. Click **Submit**.

In your component, use the Composition API to setup your reCAPTCHA:

```html
<template>
  <button @click="recaptcha">Execute recaptcha</button>
</template>

<script>
import { useReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3'

export default {
  setup() {
    const { executeRecaptcha, recaptchaLoaded } = useReCaptcha()

    const recaptcha = async () => {
      await recaptchaLoaded()
      const token = await executeRecaptcha('login')
      console.log({ token })
    }

    return {
      recaptcha
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-recaptch-v3-demo-gjul7?file=/src/App.vue)